# Boilerplate catalog skeleton

Tags: file-upload, aspnetboilerplate, catalog

I have to make a simple catalog with products image upload with boilerplate.
Has anyone done something like this? Are there public examples of catalogs source code made with AspnetBoilerplate on the internet?

Answer (score 1):

checkout the below websites.

- https://www.nopcommerce.com/
- https://www.wix.com/

But [AspnetBoilerplate](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/) is a developer friendly framework and fully open to customizations. On the other hand, you need to write code and get your hands dirty with it. For the long-term benefits, I would go with [AspnetBoilerplate](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Ready to use solution? Unlikely. AspnetBoilerPlate is for coders. So start coding. It should be fairly straightforward to hook up existing .NET Core e-commerce solution with AspNetBoilerplate features using starter template as a reference. Alternatively, you can start with AspNetBoilerplate starter template and add necessary e-commerce features like catalog listing using existing e-commerce source code as a reference.

[SimplCommerce](https://github.com/simplcommerce/SimplCommerce) is a good simple ecommerce solution also built with .NET Core and EntityFrameworkCore.